# Call selector on superview (UITableViewController)

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, selector

I have a UITableViewController with a method called "sectionOpen". In this controller I have a UITableView with custom headers, which are in fact a UIViewController. I have attached a UITapGestureRecognizer to it, it works if I call a selector on the header's View Controller.

The thing is I need to call a selector on the UITableViewController not the header's View Controller.

Here's my code:

```
// UITableViewController .m
   - (IBAction) sectionOpen:(UITapGestureRecognizer)recognizer {
     //Do Something
   }


// Header CustomSectionHeader .h
   @interface CustomSectionHeader : UIViewController {
       id delegate;
   }
   @property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;


//Header CustomSectionHeader .m
   @synthesize delegate;
- (id) initWithSection:(NSInteger)section delegate:(id)aDelegate {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.delegate = aDelegate;
        [self delegateSetUp];


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer  alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionOpen:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
        [tapGesture release];

    }

    return self;
}

- (void) delegateSetUp {
    [self setDelegate:self.delegate];
    NSLog(@"DELEGATE: %@", [self delegate]);
}
```

How do I call sectionOpen on UITableViewController from CustomSectionHeader?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
... initWithTarget:aDelegate ...
```

I have no idea what "delegateSetUp" is supposed to do; it doesn't seem to do anything.